# Magento subcategory image to big

Tags: image, magento

By default Magento is resizing my subcategory images. For some reason image is 658px wide. How can I force Magento to use default image sizes or shrink image to original size.

I have tried modifying several files, but this large size was nowhere specified

I am using Magento 1.9.1.0

See attached image[image]

Comment: How big is the image supposed to be? Did you take a look at the template files to see if they're resizing it?

Comment: Which files exactly do you mean ? I think this is the default size but I would like it smaller.